# Mongoose.js: isModified flag for attribute with default value

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a model with a default generated value that doesn't change throughout the document lifetime except in one special case.

A document may get marked as deleted using `doc.update({_id: doc._id, deleted_at: new Date()}, {overwrite: true})`

In a very special case the document may be "revived" - looked up by it's id and being worked with again afterwards.

In a pre-save hook I need to perform some action (for example store a document in another collection) whenever the document is created or revived.

Consider following simplified code:

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var someSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        immutable: {
            type: String,
            default: function () {
                return 'SomeVeryRandomValue';
            }
        }
    });

someSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    if (this.isNew || this.isModified('immutable')) {
        console.log('Processing pre-save hook!');
    }
    next();
});

var SomeModel = mongoose.model('SomeModel', someSchema, 'test');

mongoose.connection.once('open', function (err) {
    var testDoc = new SomeModel({});
    console.log('New: %j', testDoc.toObject());

    testDoc.save(function(err) {
        console.log('Initial saved: %j', testDoc.toObject());

        testDoc.update({_id: testDoc._id}, {overwrite: true}, function (err) {

            // at this point using mongo console:
            // > db.test.findOne()
            // { "_id" : ObjectId("5617b028bf84f0a93687cf67") }

            SomeModel.findById(testDoc.id, function(err, reloadedDoc) {
                console.log('Reloaded: %j', reloadedDoc.toObject());
                console.log('reloaded isModified(\'immutable\'): %j', reloadedDoc.isModified('immutable'));

                reloadedDoc.save(function(err) {
                    console.log('Re-saved: %j', reloadedDoc);
                    mongoose.connection.close();
                });
            });

        });
    });
});
```

And the script runtime output:

```
$ node mongoose-modified-test.js
New: {"_id":"5617b64c5376737b46f6bb98","immutable":"SomeVeryRandomValue"}
Processing pre-save hook!
Initial saved: {"__v":0,"_id":"5617b64c5376737b46f6bb98","immutable":"SomeVeryRandomValue"}
Reloaded: {"_id":"5617b64c5376737b46f6bb98","immutable":"SomeVeryRandomValue"}
reloaded isModified('immutable'): false
Re-saved: {"_id":"5617b64c5376737b46f6bb98","immutable":"SomeVeryRandomValue"}
```

The `immutable` is not marked as modified and IMHO it should - original document had no value for that attribute.

A work-around solution is to remove the default value for `immutable` attribute and define pre-validate hook like this one:

```
someSchema.pre('validate', function (next) {
    if (this.isNew || !this.immutable) {
        this.immutable = 'SomeVeryRandomValue';
    }
    next();
});
```

This is not exactly what I need because the value won't be generated until I try to validate/save the document. The pre/post-init hooks are not executed on `new SomeModel({})` so I can't use those.

Should I open an issue for [mongoose.js](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose)?

Comment: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3480

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.$isDefault('immutable')` can be used instead.

```
someSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    if (this.isNew || this.$isDefault('immutable')) {
        console.log('Processing pre-save hook!');
    }
    next();
});
```

Output of the script with updated pre-save hook:

```
$ node --harmony mongoose-modified-test.js
New: {"_id":"56276f0c1a2f17ae7e0a03f7","immutable":"SomeVeryRandomValue"}
Processing pre-save hook!
Initial saved: {"__v":0,"_id":"56276f0c1a2f17ae7e0a03f7","immutable":"SomeVeryRandomValue"}
Reloaded: {"_id":"56276f0c1a2f17ae7e0a03f7","immutable":"SomeVeryRandomValue"}
Processing pre-save hook!
Re-saved: {"_id":"56276f0c1a2f17ae7e0a03f7","immutable":"SomeVeryRandomValue"}
```

Thanks to @vkarpov15 for [clarification](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3480).